# Showing existence of non-negative solution to matrix equation $Ax = b$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, proof-writing, algorithms, linear-programming

I have a $m\times n$ matrix $A$, such that $m>n$. Matrix $A$ is also comprised of only the values $-1,0,1$. We also have a vector $\vec b$ that is $m\times1$. $\vec b$ only has the restrictions that its first element is non-negative, and the elements are all integers.

I want to know if there is a way to prove in polynomial time whether or not there exists a vector $\vec x$ such that every element of $\vec x$ is non-negative and

$$
A\vec x = \vec b
$$

Note the elements of $\vec x$ **do not need to be integers**

I'm trying to practice my math notation so I'm just going to rewrite the problem below, let me know if I'm wrong

Given $A$ an $m\times n$ matrix s.t. $a_{ij} \in \{-1,0,1\} \forall 1\leq i \leq m, 1\leq j \leq n$ and $\vec b \in \mathbb{Z}^m$

Prove $\exists \vec x \in \mathbb{R}^n_+ \,\, x_i \geq 0, A\vec x= \vec b$

Comment: I would write your last statement as follows. Given $A\in\{-1,0,1\}^{m\times n}$ and $b \in\mathbb{Z}^m $ with $b_1\geq0$. Prove that there exists an $x\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}^n$ such that $A x = b$.

Comment: Proper notation is $m\times n$ rather than $m\text{x}n$, and $\mathbb{R}^n$ rather than $\mathbb {R^n}.$ I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: However, I don't think this is always true. Take for example $m=n=1$. $A=-1$ and $b=1$ as counterexample. Moreover, a linear system can always be solved (either the solution is found, or it is concluded that there is no solution) in quadratic (= polynomial) time.

Comment: The font is different in comments from what it is in questions. In the question, your $m$x$n$ looked like $m\text{x}n$. You need $\times$ rather than $\text{x}.\qquad$

Comment: @StanTendijck, showing that there is no solution is also a valid answer

Comment: In that case, I am pretty sure it can be done in quadratic time.

Comment: @wjmccann It would be clearer if you changed "that there exists" to "whether or not there exists".

Comment: @StanTendijck, I was thinking it could be framed as linear programming, but I wasn't sure of the exact problem formulation

Comment: In general, I think this can not be done. If your matrix is tridiagonal (or something similar), you can do it in linear time: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is yes, as follows:

Introduce $2n=O(n)$ non-negative slack variables $s^+,s^-\geqslant0$, then solve the LP

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\min\ & \sum_{i=1}^ns_i^+ +\sum_{i=1}^ns_i^- \\
\text{s.t.}\ & Ax+s^+-s^-=b \\
& x,s^+,s^-\geqslant0
\end{array}
$$

The system has a non-negative solution iff the optimal objective value if this LP is zero. (This is actually how the two-phase simplex method finds initial feasible solutions when solving LPs). Since LPs can be solved in polynomial time, this is a polynomial time procedure.

Comment: can't you use the special structure of $A$ for a more efficient solution?

Comment: @LinAlg I would imagine so, yes. This at least gives an affirmative answer to the question